# How to Compare these Groups

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, contingency-tables

I am analyzing the accuracy of different clinicians when it comes to providing presumptive diagnoses.  I am comparing dentists and physicians for accuracy of referrals. My data is as follows: 33 cases the MD diagnosed correct, 14 cases the MD was incorrect.  115 cases the DDS diagnosed correctly. 76 cases the DDS was incorrect.

Is there a statistical difference between these two groups?  How would I calculate that using Excel?

```
    Correct Incorrect   
MD   33         14  
DDS  115        76
```

Comment: When you added the `[statistical]` tag, did you notice it said, "This tag is deprecated. DO NOT USE IT"?

Comment: Nope. But I am new to this so I wasn't paying much attention.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is a hypotheses contrast about the difference in proportions.

Let $p_{MD}$, $p_{DDS}$ the (population) proportion of correctly diagnosed cases for the two clinician types, and $\hat{p}_{MD}=\frac{33}{33+14}$, $\hat{p}_{DDS}=\frac{115}{115+76}$.

You test the null hypothesis $H_0:\,\,\,p_{DDS}-p_{MD}=0$ against the alternative $H_1:\,\,\,p_{DDS}-p_{MD}\neq 0$.

The total proportion of correct diagnoses for both samples is $\hat{p}=\frac{33+115}{33+14+115+76}$.

The sample sizes are $n_{DDS}=115+76$, $n_{MD}=33+14$.

You build the statistic

$$Z=\frac{\hat{p}_{DDS}-\hat{p}_{MD}}{\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})\left(\frac{1}{n_{MD}}+\frac{1}{n_{DDS}}\right)}}.$$

This follows a standard normal distribution, so you have to pick a threshold of that distribution to compare to. For instance, for an $\alpha=0.05$ significance (or $95\%$ confidence in your response), you pick $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=1.96$ and $-z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=-1.96$.

If the $Z$ statistic you computed is greater than $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ or smaller than $-z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$, then you can state the proportions are different at the $95\%$ level. Otherwise, they are not significantly different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [chi-squared test of independence](http://www.real-statistics.com/chi-square-and-f-distributions/independence-testing/) to answer the question "Is diagnosis accuracy different in DDSs vs MDs?"

In excel, you'll want to enter your data more or less as you have presented them here, in a 2x2 cell arrangement. Then you have to make a second similar 2x2 table of the expected counts for each cell. Each cell should be 
$row total * column total / grand total$

For example, in your case, the expected counts for the Correct MD cell would be

$(33 + 14) * (33 + 115)/(33 + 14 + 115 + 76) = 22.23$

Fill that in for all four cells in the expected counts table.
Then you can use the function [CHISQ.TEST()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHISQ-TEST-function-2e8a7861-b14a-4985-aa93-fb88de3f260f) to get the p value associated with the chi-squared test of independence --- a significant p value (generally, p < .05) means the two factors are NOT independent, i.e. the diagnostic accuracy depends on which degree they have.